# 3 docker nodes of ElasticSearch in one VM

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, virtual-machine, esxi

I have access to three VMs in a server with VMware ESXi, Im going to install Logstash in one VM, kibana in another, and Elastic in the more resourcefull one, and to have redundancy I was thinking to install three nodes of elasticsearch with docker.

What do you think about this configuration? 
Is there any other configuration that you would recommend for the limited resources that I have?
thats all the resources that I have available, but if I can ask for another VM o host another node of ES, would be better than create the three nodes of docker in one VM?

Comment: IME Elasticsearch (and other databases) are more often than not disk-bound, so adding additional copies of the software sharing the same disk doesn't gain you anything.  If not that then you're running heavy queries and they're CPU-bound, and again unless you have more physical cores there's no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you will install 3 containers on same machine, then its useless. Point of 3 node cluster is if one goes down you are still alive with 2 other. In this case its better to have one but powerful node.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, what counts is the total number of cores and RAM, not the number of VMs. You could have them all in one VM if it is provisioned properly. Multiple VMs come needed if/when you need to implement a certain level of redundancy.

Comment: I will need redundancy, that why Im thinking in docker